# Does Apple Store, Android Market accept Mobile Apps made using jQuery , jQueryMobile and Phone-Gap

Tags: android, jquery, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making an application for online blog I am using JqueryMobile features to design the application and Phone Gap to add features to it like GPS to check location and other features from Mobile.

```
     <div id="index" data-role="page">
         <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="nav_header">
             <h1>Deals</h1>
             <nav data-role="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#index">home page</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#info">settings</a></li>
                </ul>
             </nav>
         </div>
         <div data-role="content">
             <a href="#search" data-role="button">Search Blog</a>
             <a href="#search" data-role="button">New Blog </a>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Would it be acceptable if writen in this format ? I am totally newbie in this. What else should I do or improve if I am missing somewhere in making this?   Thanks

Comment: If you could get a mobile application running with a typewriter and a toaster it would get accepted to the Android Market.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phonegap works for the apple store but occaisonally the acceptance time is higher then a normal iphone app http://www.macstories.net/news/apple-phonegap-framework-is-ok-for-the-app-store/

Comment: in general, trying to stick to valid web standards for XHTML, CSS, javascript will help. the better your code functions correctly as an actual website, the better off you will be. i would check out http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596805784/ and http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/41524872/JQuery%20Mobile%20Tutorial%20%28iOS%29

Comment: Don't worry too much about getting XHTML right though, use HTML5, especially with jQuery Mobile.

Comment: @JasonDean I would be using Json instead along with HTML/HTML5 CSS/CSS3 as applicable

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly sure that you'd be fine on the Android marketplace, there are very few rules other than no malware. I can't help you regarding iOS though.